# A folder named Folder with contact files created on destination mailbox

Tags: command-line, imap

I tried to find imapsync options and parameters to sync and delete older emails on destination zimbra 8.7.7 mailbox from zimbra 7.1.4. 2 tests were successful so far but with additional folder named Folder with contact files in it.

Below is command in a shell script and its options used:

```
host1="IP-source"
host2="IP-destination"
username="user@domain"
admin_account_password="zimbra-admin-password"
imapsync \
  --host1 "$host1" --host2 "$host2" --useuid --delete2 \
  --user1 "$username" --authuser1 admin \
  --ssl1 --authmech1 PLAIN \
  --password1 "$admin_account_password" \
  --user2 "$username" --authuser2 admin \
  --ssl2 --authmech2 PLAIN  \
  --password2 "$admin_account_password" \
  --maxsize 52428800 --buffersize 8192000 \
  --nofoldersizes --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates \
  --authmech2 PLAIN \
  --exclude '(?i)\b(Junk|Spam|Trash)\b' \
  --regextrans2 "s,&AAo-|&AA0ACg-|&AA0ACgANAAo-(?=/|$),,g" \
  --regexflag 's/\\\\(?!Answered|Flagged|Deleted|Seen|Recent|Draft)[^\s]*\s*//ig' --debugflags \
  --regextrans2 's,:,-,g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\",'\'',g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\s+(?=/|$),,g' \
  --regextrans2 "s,^(Briefcase|Calendar|Contacts|Emailed Contacts|Notebook|Tasks)(?=/|$), $1 Folder,ig" \
  --regextrans2 's,\",-,g' \
```

imapsync 1.727 on CentOS 7

So, what caused that folder to appear and how not to make it not appear?

Comment: And the question is how to **not** get that folder?

Comment: Maybe the Blank in "Emailed Contacts" ?

Comment: when I removed "Emailed Contacts" from regextrans2, I got error "Err 1/1: Could not create folder [Emailed Contacts] from [Emailed Contacts]: 22 NO CREATE failed: mailbox already exists"

Comment: my bad, I have to exclude both contacts folder

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to exclude both Emailed Contacts & Contacts folder seen by imapsync.

diff

```
16c
  --exclude '(?i)\b(Junk|Spam|Trash|Emailed \Contacts|Contacts)\b' \
.
```